# Knockout.js adding new items to array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having trouble being able to programatically add elements to an observable array contained within a table of data.

Each row of the table has a different array that I wish to affect.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='liveExample'>     
<h2>Cases</h2>
<div id='contactsList'>
    <table class='contactsEditor'>
        <tr>
            <th>Case Number</th>
            <th>Stage</th>
            <th>Users</th>
            <th>Ids</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: appearances ">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind='value: caseNumber' />
                </td>
                <td><input data-bind='value: caseStage' /></td>
                <td> 
                    <ul  data-bind="foreach: subjects">
                        <li style="list-style-type:none;"><label data-bind="text: Name"/></li>    
                    </ul>   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: ids">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input data-bind='value: $data' /></td>
                                <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeId'>Delete</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addId'>Add number</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>     
<p>
    <button data-bind='click: save, enable:appearances().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
</p>     
<textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
```

​

The data and JavaScript looks like this:

```
enter code here
var initialData = [{
"Number": "12000009",
"Stage": "Inital",
"Subjects": [{
    "Name": "Andrew McAdam"},
{
    "Name": "Patrick Brown"}],
"Ids": [1]},
{
"Number": "12000010",
"Stage": "Inital",
"Subjects": [{
    "Name": "John Smith"}],
"Ids": [2, 3]},
{
"Number": "12000011",
"Stage": "Inital",
"Subjects": [{
    "Name": "James Bonner"}],
"Ids": [4]},
{
"Number": "12000012",
"Stage": "Processed",
"Subjects": [{
    "Name": "Henrik Dalgleish"}],
"Ids": [5]}]

var AppearancesModel = function(appearances) {
var self = this;
self.appearances = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(appearances, function(appearance) {
    return {
        caseNumber: appearance.Number,
        caseStage: appearance.Stage,
        subjects: ko.observableArray(appearance.Subjects),
        ids: ko.observableArray(appearance.Ids)
    };
}));

self.addId = function(appearance) {
    appearance.ids.push("");
};

self.removeId = function(id) {
    $.each(self.appearances(), function() {
        this.ids.remove(id)
    })
};

self.save = function() {
    self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.appearances), null, 2));
};

self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppearancesModel(initialData));​
```

The problem I have is that after the clicking the Add button and entering a value the value in the array is empty string (the value I added when creating the new array element).

I think the issue is that I am adding the new item to the array before I have a value, but I thought that it would be bound to the new inpute so when I executed the Save function the new value would be reflected.

The JsFiddle of the above is at http://jsfiddle.net/amcgoldrick/3h9GZ/

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Following the advice from @Mark-Robinson, I added the following to map the original ids `ids: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(appearance.Ids, function(id) { return ko.observable(id)}))` and my original ids are displayed.  The issue I have now is that 'appearance.ids.push({id: ko.observable("")});' adds an object with an id property to an array of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values that you add to your `ids` `observableArray` are not observable therefore the binding is only one way. If you want to update the value inside the `observableArray` then you need to make the elements inside the `observableArray` observable.

So instead of:

```
self.addId = function(appearance) {
    appearance.ids.push("");
};
```

You would have:

```
self.addId = function(appearance) {
    appearance.ids.push({id: ko.observable("")});
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5wKjk/3/ for a working example. (I've not added code to map your existing ids as I just wanted to demonstrate the principles involved and didn't have time).

Comment: Excellent, that helps me get a bit closer.

Comment: The use of `appearance.ids.push({id: ko.observable("")});` cause an object with a property `id` and a value of `""` to be added.  I can't workout how to add a simple integer.

Comment: Have you looked at the fiddle? In the markup I have changed the bindings so they deal with the 'id' property. Also, if you want to bind your value to a input box then when you enter something into the textbox knockout will always write a string back into your model. Therefore, I wouldn't be concerned with whether your value is an integer or a string. After all, 1 == "1" in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry Mark, I got a bit mixed up with my JSFiddle windows.  What you supplied was perfect.  The code required to map the existing ids is `ids: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(appearance.Ids, function(x) {
                return {
                    id: x
                };
            }))`